# Get first record when all fields are identical except ID and Timestamp?

Tags: sql, intersystems-cache

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT  TOP 6 *
FROM    HS_IHE_ATNA_Repository.Aggregation
WHERE   EventType = 'Retrieve Document Set'
```

It returns data that looks similar to this:

```
ID     TimeStamp    tid    Fruit      Color       User     EventType
1      12:30:31     001    Apple      Red         Paul     Retrieve Document Set
2      12:30:32     001    Apple      Red         Paul     Retrieve Document Set
3      12:31:03     002    Orange     Orange      Steve    Retrieve Document Set
4      12:31:04     002    Orange     Orange      Steve    Retrieve Document Set
5      12:34:12     003    Banana     Yellow      Paul     Retrieve Document Set
6      12:34:13     003    Banana     Yellow      Paul     Retrieve Document Set
```

I would like my query to only return records 1, 3 and 5.  Essentially, everything with a unique tid.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT  distinct(*)
FROM    HS_IHE_ATNA_Repository.Aggregation a
WHERE   EventType = 'Retrieve Document Set'
AND     TimeStamp = (select min(b.TimeStamp) from from HS_IHE_ATNA_Repository.Aggregation b 
                      WHERE b.tid = a.tid)
ORDER BY ID asc
```

Comment: I don't understand why this would do anything different.  Record 1 is still distinct from record 2.  I tested it anyway and it did not work.

Comment: I have to limit the rows due to table size, but doing `select distinct top 10 *` returns the exact same results as `select top 10 *`

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to exclude the ID row from the `Distinct` selection.  The ID is making the SQL return every row as being distinct, so dropping it **should** just give you the records you want.  Edited answer...

Comment: I need the timestamp.  I'm almost positive the solution will involve MAX(Timestamp) somehow.

Comment: or maybe group by?

Comment: I think in this case you'd want to use MIN rather than Max - I've edited again and hopefully this will do what you needed...

Comment: I think that did it.  `min` and `max` are really irrelevant since they are milliseconds apart.  Thanks though

Comment: Glad we got there in the end! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use GROUP BY creatively:

```
SELECT  TOP 6 MAX(TimeStamp), *
FROM    HS_IHE_ATNA_Repository.Aggregation
WHERE   EventType = 'Retrieve Document Set'
GROUP BY tid||Fruit||Color||User
```

This groups all rows with the same tid, Fruit, Color, User. Alternatively you can concat with concat function:
`GROUP BY {fn CONCAT(tid,{fn CONCAT(Fruit,{fn CONCAT(Color,User)})})}`

Comment: What do the pipes do?

Comment: It's a concat symbol.

Comment: Are you sure they work with [tag:Intersystems-cache]?  I'll test soon.

Comment: Very sure.  Try `Select 1||2` -  it yields `12`

Comment: Also, can you provide a class definition for this table. There are, I think, a better performing alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain the sequential concatenation? `||||`

Comment: It was a typo. Fixed now.

Comment: I see, thanks.  And I'm not sure I can get to the cls definition but I'll try.

Comment: `[SELECT - 0 row(s), 2156.781 secs]  Server closed communication device`  I'll try again :|

Comment: Yes, well first the GROUP BY clause would be executed for all rows, regardless of the `TOP` clause.